# Django Rest queryset running two times

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi Why Django calling this query set two times ?

```
 class AccountListView(ListCreateAPIView):

            serializer_class = AccountSerializer

            def get_queryset(self):
                print 'get query set'

                return Accounts.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: In what context is it being called? Please show your view and URLs.

Comment: Do you use this `APIView` with `UpdateModelMixin`? If so the behavior may be due to queryset caching. Please check the `_prefetched_objects_cache` setting of the queryset objects which the function returns. The `get_queryset` will be called twice within `update` function of the `mixin` class.

Comment: @Daniel. This is just to get the acccounts information associated with the user GET request of /accounts/.

Comment: @gdlmx. I will check it. but this is just a get request.

Answer (score 1):

as anwered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41872318/9187705) it is because you are using the BrowsableAPI, I tested same api in Postman and in browser, when using Postman commands ran once while using browser commands ran twice!