# Django Rest Framework view get_queryset is called twice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this ModelViewset and a ModelSerializer

```
class GenerarFacturaViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializer.FacturaSerializer 

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset = []


        _nro = self.request.query_params.get('nro', None)
        venta_id = self.request.query_params.get('ventaid', None)

        if (venta_id is None or _nro is None):
            raise exceptions.ParseError("Parametros invalidos")

        nro = int(_nro)
        venta = models.Venta.objects.get(id=venta_id)

        if models.Factura.objects.filter(numero=nro):
            raise exceptions.ParseError("Ya existe una factura con ese numero")

        venta.generar_factura(nro)
        print("Factura generada con nro: ", nro)

        self.queryset = models.Factura.objects.filter(numero=nro)

        return self.queryset
```

Then when this ModelViewset is called the first time every work correctly until the return sentence then the get_queryset method is called again. I want to know why?

Other detail is that when the second exception is raised in the first get_queryset call, this is show as rest framework normal template but if it is raised in the second called, it is show in the django error template with the traceback and error messages.

thanks in advance

EDIT: I found a best way to do that i want
The Linovia answer is correct and then i improve somethings.

To clarify, i need two parameters "venta_id" and "numero" to create a object "factura". In my first attempt i try get this parameters from request data, validate it and call the model method to create the object. All on get_queryset method. But i think it is not a good way to do it.

Then i create a new view and a serializer for this porpuse.

```
class AddProductoViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = serializer.AddProductoSerializer
queryset = models.Venta.objects.all()
http_method_names = ['post', 'head']

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    venta_id = request.data.get('venta_id', None)
    producto_id = request.data.get('producto_id', None)
    cantidad = request.data.get('cantidad', None)

    serializer_r = serializer.AddProductoSerializer(data=request.data)
    if (serializer_r.is_valid(raise_exception=True)):
        print("Datos validos")
        venta = models.Venta.objects.get(id=venta_id)

        if models.Venta.productos.filter(id=producto_id):
            vpd = VentaProductoDetalle.objects.filter(venta_id=venta_id, producto_id=producto_id)[0]
            vpd.cantidad += int(cantidad)
            vpd.save()
        else:
            vpd = VentaProductoDetalle()
            vpd.venta = venta
            vpd.producto = models.Producto.objects.get(id=producto_id)
            vpd.cantidad = int(cantidad)
            vpd.save()
    queryset = models.Venta.objects.get(id=venta_id)
    serializer_r = serializer.VentaSerializer(queryset)
    return Response(serializer_r.data)
```

The serializer class:

```
class PostFacturaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

venta_id = serializers.IntegerField()
numero = serializers.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = models.Factura

def validate(self, attrs):

    try:
        venta_id = attrs['venta_id']
        numero = attrs['numero']

    except KeyError as e:
        print("Error: ", e)
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            "Campos no recibidos correctamente")


    if (models.Factura.objects.filter(numero=numero)):
        print("ya existe")
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            "Ya existe una factura con ese nombre"
        )

    return attrs
```

then i remove the get_queryset override method, it is not necessary anymore.

Now, how you can see, i validate data on serializer so i just call the is_valid method on view's create method.I think this is a best way.

P.D:apologies for my bad english.

Comment: why did you define `queryset` and `get_queryset` simultaneously ? defining one of them is enough... according to your code, you can remove the line : `queryset = None`...

Comment: @Enix i changed the code, but this no make diference

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Then when this ModelViewset is called the first time every work correctly until the return sentence then the get_queryset method is called again. I want to know why?

If you're using the BrowsableAPI, it'll call the `get_queryset` again in order to display the forms.

> Other detail is that when the second exception is raised in the first get_queryset call, this is show as rest framework normal template but if it is raised in the second called, it is show in the django error template with the traceback and error messages.

No idea about that one. This may be the sign that you have another exception during the processing of the initial exception.
However, `get_queryset` is not supposed to raise exceptions.

Comment: Maybe you are right but how can I validate my query parameters out of get_queryset? This parameters are present on the URl

Comment: That should be done in the view before it calls the get_queryset.

Comment: Your answer is correct but i have a better way to do this, can i check your answer as the solution and edit my question to include a better way?

Comment: Feel free to do so.

Comment: Is there anyone with a solution for this?

Comment: @EliasPrado the 2 calls won't happen if you are not using the BrowsableAPI which should be the case unless it's a human interacting with the API in which case, it should not lead to a performance issue.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am seeing but it should not happen. I saw that it get the method that is currently available such as 400 and then it list an error message to explain the 400 with a GET. I am almost sure that is why it happen but it shouldn't.

Comment: if I remember correctly, the 2nd request is performed to figure out whether or not you are allowed to update the resource. should probably not happen with R/O views but not 100% sure here and don't have the time to dig